# Rails 4 deployment - js asset error 402, but app running fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, asset-pipeline

I am a little bit lost regarding the asset cleaning on deployment...

I deployed ( august 29) my app ( Capistrano) with a **pages-frontend.js** file
( reference in the *html application layout*, and pre-compiled in *initializers/assets*

Today I changed  its name to  **pages.fronted.js** ( in both html and assets.rb files ), deployed and run again...

As I needed to identify a bug, I **removed** all references to this js file  ( from the html and assets.rb) and I deployed again
I was right , the little bug disappear.. 
BUT

I am surprised to see these 2 compiles files listed in the public/assets of the current app....

why do they not disappear from the list ?
removing an asset file from the local project, committing it to the git repo, the deploying should have cleared it ...
if not , what ma I missing to force it to disappear ?

thanks for enlightenment

Comment: I believe you need to explicitly remove these files (or all public asset files) in your Cap file, otherwise, your deploy is just "overwriting/adding" to your existing public asset files.  If you explicitly remove them on your production server, they should not be restored in your next deploy.

Comment: thanks your right .. that's what I did .. ( praying for not to fool my deployed ap..)

Comment: lol prayer is generally an excellent idea but should not be needed in this case - if you did as you said, your app should not be looking for those assets.